# Constructor is undefined in Java class

Tags: java, class, undefined

I want to print out the `Person` objects first- and lastname.

This is my PersonTest class that runs the file and gets information from Person class:

```
package pckg;

public class PersonTest extends Person {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person firstperson = new Person("James", "Bond");

        String firstname = firstperson.getFirstname();
        String lastname = firstperson.getLastname();

        System.out.println("Person's first name is " + firstname);
        System.out.println("My name is " + firstperson.getLastname() + ",");
        System.out.println(firstperson);
        System.out.println("Person is " + firstperson);
    }

}
```

Now it says "The constructor Person(String, String) is undefined".

So my problem is, what am I supposed to write in Person.class to make this work?
I've tried this so far:

```
package pckg;

public class Person {

    public String Firstname, Lastname;


    public String getFirstname() {
        return Firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return Lastname;
    }

}
```

Comment: Whenever you are going to create an object for any class program will automatically invoke the default constructor for that class. If you want any user defined constructor then you should define the respective method for contructor inside your class as mentioned in below solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, you haven't defined a constructor with the signature `Person(String, String)`.

Do that and the error will go away:

```
public class Person {

    public String Firstname, Lastname;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.Firstname = firstName;
        this.Lastname = lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return Firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return Lastname;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a constructor yourself. If you write `new Person("James", "Bond");` the compiler doesn't know what you mean. What is the string `"James"`? (is it the `Firstname`, `Lastname`, or something completely different?)

Just add this code to your class:

```
public Person(String fname, String lname) {
    Firstname = fname;
    Lastname = lname;
}
```

This function gets called each time you call `new Person`. You simply take the two strings and store them in the correct class variables.

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, you have no constructor implemented for the class Person

Your edited code should be

```
public class Person {

    public String Firstname, Lastname;

    public Person(String Firstname, String Lastname){
        this.Firstname = Firstname;
        this.Lastname  = Lastname;
    } 
    public String getFirstname() {
        return Firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return Lastname;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to call a constructor that does not exist here:

```
Person firstperson = new Person("James", "Bond");
```

There is no constructor in your `Person` class that contains two `String` paramters:

```
Person(String firstName, String secondName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.secondName = secondName;
}
```

Either add that constructor to your `Person` class, or use the implicit zero-argument constructor and set those values separately:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.firstName = "James";
person.secondName = "Bond";
```